# Are ETS bulk operations atomic?

Tags: erlang, ets

Specifically, `:ets.tab2list` and `:ets.file2tab`. Does these functions "snapshot" the table state, or can other operations interleave reads and writes while these functions complete?

Comment: Did you mean `tab2file` instead of `tab2list`?

Comment: Both, I'd expect them to have the same guarantees or lack thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html):

> Functions that internally traverse over a table, like `select` and `match`, give the same guarantee as `safe_fixtable`.

Where

> [...] function `safe_fixtable` can be used to guarantee that a sequence of first/1 and next/2 calls traverse the table without errors and that each existing object in the table is visited exactly once, even if another (or the same) process simultaneously deletes or inserts objects into the table.

And specifically related to your question:

> Nothing else is guaranteed; in particular objects that are inserted or deleted during such a traversal can be visited once or not at all.

---

**EDIT**

[`ets:tab2list/1`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/ets.erl#L735) calls `ets:match_object/2` which is a built-in function (BIF) implemented in C. The implementation [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/erts/emulator/beam/erl_db.c#L3084) is using the BIF `ets_select2`, which is the implementation for `ets:select/2`.

`ets:file2tab` ends up calling [`load_table/3`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/ets.erl#L1324) which simply uses `ets:insert/2`.

The code for `ets:tab2file/3` in [`ets.erl`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/ets.erl), uses [`ets:select/3`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/ets.erl#L842) to get the first chunk and then [`ets:select/1`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/ets.erl#L902) to get the rest of the chunks in the table.

Comment: I don't believe these docs answer the question. It's unclear whether tab2x and x2tab use select/match, safe_fixtable, or some other mechanism.

Comment: @knite You are right, I had followed the code in `ets.erl` but failed to mention that :P. I updated the answer with this information.